# How do I make an app bar not dismissable

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, appbar

I have an app bar in my Windows 8 application which should not be dismissable by the user during a certain time.

Setting its `sticky` property prevents it from being dismissed by clicking anywhere on the screen, however, you can still dismiss it by pressing windows-key + z, right clicking, or swiping on the bottom or top of the screen.

I have tried calling `preventDefault()` on the `onbeforehide` event but that didn't work. According to the documentation, [the event is cancelable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212517.aspx). Here's the code:

```
document.getElementById("placementAppbar").addEventListener(
"beforehide", 
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

What can I do to stop the appbar from being dismissed by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See I was going through the link and

I found the following quote

**Don't provide an alternate behavior for the Win+Z keypress combination in your app. Develop an app bar or similar context menu, and display it when the user presses the Windows key in conjunction with the Z key. Register for the KeyDown and AcceleratorKeyActivated events to determine when these two keys have been pressed.**

So i really think if you can work this the other way round like windows + z do some thing else. I mean override the functionality then it might work

Here's the link

[App bar guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx)

This is just a suggestion see if you can work your way round else I dont think there's an option.

Comment: I guess if it's discouraged in the guidelines, I should probably find some other way of displaying the context sensitive commands. Thanks though!

Comment: Actually according to guidelines top app bar should be only used for navigation. :) make your own grid control and have some good animations :)